# Why doesn't std::sort use my operator< implementation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Why doesn't std::sort use my `operator<` implementation in [this code](http://ideone.com/f48Cu9)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool operator<(
    const tuple<int, int>& t1,
    const tuple<int, int>& t2
) {
    return get<1>(t1) > get<1>(t2);// `>` so that it gets sorted in reverse
}

int main() {
    vector<tuple<int, int>> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v.push_back(make_tuple(0, i));
    }
    cout << "before sort: ";
    for (auto& x : v) { cout << get<1>(x) << ", "; }
    cout << endl;

    auto v2 = v;
    sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    cout << "after sort(begin, end): ";
    for (auto& x : v2) { cout << get<1>(x) << ", "; }
    cout << endl;

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& t1, auto& t2) {
        return get<1>(t1) > get<1>(t2);// `>` so that it gets sorted in reverse
    });
    cout << "after sort(begin, end, comparator): ";
    for (auto& x : v) { cout << get<1>(x) << ", "; }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
before sort: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
after sort(begin, end): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
after sort(begin, end, comparator): 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0,
```

The output I expected is:

```
before sort: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
after sort(begin, end): 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 
after sort(begin, end, comparator): 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0,
```

Comment: If you see this http://ideone.com/0h1rYa it works after moving your custom `operator<` directly into the standard namespace (_not suggesting that as a good idea_).  So when matching `std::tuple<int, int>` to `operator<` it finds the standard defined one (in `namespace std`) first (and/or as a better match).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with how name lookup works in function templates (commonly referred to as two-phase lookup). `std::sort` is defined in `<algorithm>`, and the lookup for `<` will find those names in scope at the point of the template definition (which yours is not) and those names in the associated namespaces of the dependent function arguments (which for `std::tuple` would be `namespace std`, which also does not include yours).

Since the arguments in question are in namespace `std`, it's actually undefined behavior to add your overload into that namespace. So your options are to either stick with the default behavior (which would be lexicographical `<`) or to provide your own custom comparator (as you do in your question).